# How to process the Promise returned from parent Promise chain with various possible outcomes

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In my Node.JS web app, I have a database layer module (`db_location.js`). Depending the response type from the node-fetch call, it returns a json() or a text() promise depending on the content type from the response of the fetch call.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const p_conf = require('../parse_config');

const db_location = {
    getLocations: function() {
        return fetch(`${p_conf.SERVER_URL}/parse` + '/classes/GCUR_LOCATION', { method: 'GET', headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'APPLICATION_ID',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'restAPIKey'
        }}).then(function(res1) {           
            const contentType = res1.headers.get('content-type').toLowerCase();
            if (contentType.includes("application/json"))
                return res1.json();  // RETURNS A PROMISE
            else
                return res1.text();  // RETURNS A PROMISE
        }).catch(err => Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ "Error": err })));
    }

};

module.exports = db_location
```

The module is called by a Express route `locations.js`.

```
const db_location = require('../db/db_location');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db_location.getLocations()
    .then(function(result) {
        /*
        IF RESULT IS JSON, DO PROCESSING 1;
        ELSE RESULT IS TEXT, DO PROCESSING 2.
        */
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return next(err);
    })

});
```

As the response from the fetch cannot be passed down the promise chain, there is no way to retrieve the content type from in the route code.

Comment: code for text ... json is just text anyway, so you can always JSON.parse any text - oh, you've already done that - so what's the issue? in the body of `.then(function(result) {` check if `result` is an object or a string - simples

Comment: to clarify your comments in your code ... `return res1.json();  // RETURNS A PROMISE THAT RESOLVES TO AN OBJECT` and `return res1.text();  // RETURNS A PROMISE THAT RESOLVES TO A STRING`

Answer (score 0):

Well Javascript strings are valid Json data. So in theory you can't really tell whether something was Json or not unless you transform it after `res1.json()`

You can check if something is of type string with the following in location.js

```
if(typeof result === 'string'){ /* it's a string*/ }
else{ /* it's something else */}
```